# Variables after fork

Tags: c, fork

Here is a code:

```
int i = 0;
pid_t pid;
puts("Hello, World!");
puts("");
pid = fork();
if (pid) {
    i = 42;
}   
printf("%p\n", &i);
printf("%d\n", i);
puts("");
```

And output

```
Hello, World!

0x7fffc2490278
42

0x7fffc2490278
0
```

Program print Hello, World! one time, so child process wasn't start from the beginning and it wasn't re-define variables. Adresses of variables are same. So they are same. But I change i's value in parent process which is executed first, it didn't change for child process. Why?

Comment: Uh, you didn't change "i" until *after* the fork().  You might see the display in any order - parent first, or parent after child.  But *only* the parent will show "42"; the child will always be "0".

Comment: this line, after the call to fork(): 'if(pid)' is not correct.   fork() returns a -1 when an error occurs (and they do occasionally occur).  So the code will act as if it were a successful parent when the fork() actually failed.   There are several system function calls where the return code should always be checked to assure the operation was successful.  fork() is one of those system functions.   The line would be much better as: 'if(pid > 0)'  Even better yet would be to also check if pid < 0 and handle the error

Answer (score 16, accepted):

> Adresses of variables are same. So they are same. But I change i's value in parent process which is executed first, it didn't change for child process. Why?

The addresses are in the scope of a process. They are virtual addresses. Address `0x7fffc2490278` in the parent process and `0x7fffc2490278` in the child process are different physical addresses.

Comment: @thoron - did you not realize that addresses are unique *per process*?  That 0x10000 in one process is a completely different physical address than 0x10000 in another process?  Or that "logical address" 0x10000 can *change* to a *different* physical address *while the process is running*?  Look here for more details: http://computer.howstuffworks.com/virtual-memory.htm

Answer (score 6):

When you do `fork()`, a whole process will be created including variables. So `i` in the parent is not `i` of the child. They have same virtual address but not same physical address.  The modification is completely independent.

Answer (score 3):

From the [man page](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/fork.2.html) for fork:

> On success, the PID of the child process is returned in the parent,
>          and 0 is returned in the child.  On failure, -1 is returned in the
>          parent, no child process is created, and errno is set appropriately.

That is, for the parent pid is being set to a number greater than 0 (or -1 if failure which you should also check for).

`if(pid)` evaluates to `if(true)`

And it will execute for the parent. The child, however, gets 0 assigned to `pid` (that's how it knows it's the child).

`if(0)` evaluates to `if(false)`

and thus the value of i does not change.

However, because of abstractions the process sees memory in **virtual addresses** (virtual address space which is *exactly* copied with `fork`). Only the kernel can manage physical addresses and the process communicates with kernel to get this memory (the process just says *"put this variable `i` at this address: `0x7fffc2490278`"* and the kernel will basically map it wherever it wants to). As far as the process knows, it's the only process asking for memory and that's why their addresses are the "same".

Comment: if(-1) will execute. everything is true except 0. but this is just test code, i just hang around. :D It should be pid>0.

Answer (score 2):

Variables live in the virtual address space of the process. Address space of a process is local to that process. The fact that you see the same address in two processed does not mean that you are accessing the same variable. Not at all.

Address values make sense only within the context of its own process. It makes no sense to compare the addresses from different processes' address spaces.

Variable `i` in parent process is completely separate from variable `i` in child process. You changed only one `i` (the parent's one), which is exactly what you observe in the output.